# Sortable Accordion not working after dragging

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sortable accordion, which works fine. I basically use this example http://jsfiddle.net/qN7b8/5/. However, - as in the jsfiddle -  after one panel has been dragged and dropped again, I need to click twice on an element to reveal its content.

Here's the JavaScript code:

```
var stop = false;
$("#accordion h3").click(function(event) {
if (stop) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    stop = false;
}
});
$("#accordion").accordion({
header: "> div > h3"
})
.sortable({
axis: "y",
handle: "h3",
stop: function() {
    stop = true;
}
});
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I got it to work by deleting `code` event.stopImmediatePropagation(); `code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `stopImmediatePropagation()` by `stopPropagation()`  http://jsfiddle.net/ouadie/RckPm/